# How do I run something as an applet and application?

Tags: java, applet

I'm working on this project and I need it run as an applet and an application. This is what I have but I stuck on where to go because I can't find anything on the internet. Are there any resources or does someone have some quick advice to give me?

```
public class Project extends JApplet {

public void init() {

    try {
        URL pictureURL = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "sample.jpg");
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(pictureURL);
        myIcon = new ImageIcon(myPicture);
        myLabel = new JLabel(myIcon);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(bio);
    add(bio, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pane.add(play);
    getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    play.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream("sample.mp3");
                player = new Player (FIS);
                player.play();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }}});
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.getContentPane().add();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.show();
}

private JPanel pane = new JPanel();
private TextArea bio = new TextArea("Bio");
private JButton play = new JButton("Play");
private Image myPicture;
private ImageIcon icon;
private JLabel label;
private Player player;

}
```

Comment: @Marco13 no worries, that why you get to pick if you believe the edits help. I already believe your answer was enough to be satisfied hence the reason I picked the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to run something as an applet and as an application, there are several caveats.

Applets have a certain [life cycle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) that must be obeyed. One can add the applet to the content pane of the `JFrame` and manually call `init()`, but in general, if the applet expects its `start()` or `stop()` methods to be called, things may become tricky...

More importantly: The way how resources are handled is different between applets and applications.

Handling files in applets (e.g. with a `FileInputStream`) may have security implications, and will plainly not work in some cases - e.g. when the applet is embedded into a website. (Also see [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)).

Conversely, when running this as an application, calling `getDocumentBase()` does not make sense. There simply is no "document base" for an application.

---

Nevertheless, it is possible to write a program that can be shown as an Applet or as an Application. The main difference will then be whether the main `JPanel` is placed into a `JApplet` or into a `JFrame`, and how data is read.

One approach for reading data that works for applets as well as for applications is via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")`, given that the respective file is in the class path.

I hesitated a while, whether I should post an example, targeting the main question, or whether I should modify your code so that it works. I'll do both:

Here is an example that can be executed as an Applet or as an Application. It will read and display a "sample.jpg". (This file is currently basically expected to be "in the same directory as the .class-file". More details about resource handling, classpaths and stream handling are beyond the scope of this answer)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AppletOrApplicationExample extends JApplet
{
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        add(new AppletOrApplicationMainComponent());
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new AppletOrApplicationMainComponent());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class AppletOrApplicationMainComponent extends JPanel
{
    public AppletOrApplicationMainComponent()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.jpg");
        if (stream == null)
        {
            add(new JLabel("Resource not found"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
                add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                add(new JLabel("Could not load image"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            }
        }

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Text...");
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("Button was clicked");
    }
}
```

---

---

And here is something that is still a bit closer to your original code. However, I'd **strongly** recommend to factor out the actual application logic as far as possible. For example, your main GUI component should then **not** be the applet itself, but a `JPanel`. Resources should not be read directly via `FileInputStream`s or URLs from the document base, but only from `InputStreams`. This is basically the code that you posted, with the *fewest modifications that are necessary to get it running as an applet or an application*:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Module5Assignment2 extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.jpg");
            if (stream == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Resource not found");
            }
            else
            {
                myPicture = ImageIO.read(stream);
                icon = new ImageIcon(myPicture);
                label = new JLabel(icon);
                add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        add(bio);
        add(bio, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pane.add(play);
        getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream("sample.mp3");
                    // player = new Player (FIS);
                    // player.play();
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        // ******PRETTY SURE I NEED TO ADD SOMETHING HERE*************
        Module5Assignment2 contents = new Module5Assignment2();
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        contents.init();
        // *************************************************************

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.show();
    }

    private JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    private TextArea bio = new TextArea(
        "This is the bio of Christian Sprague; he doesn't like typing things.");
    private JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    private Image myPicture;
    private ImageIcon icon;
    private JLabel label;
    // private Player player;

}
```